# sapui5 how can i get selected item from value help into table cell?

Tags: sapui5

I have a table.a column consists of input fields. How can I get value from `searchHelpDialog` to table item?

Below is a sample table:

[image: Image Description]

And the value help dialog:

[image: Image Description]

Answer (score 1):

You can add the id of the field as custom data to your value help dialog.
You can get the id from the oEvent.

```
openValueHelpDialog: function(oEvent) {
    var oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment();
    var oField = new sap.ui.core.CustomData();
    oField.setKey("field");
    oField.setValue(oEvent.getParameter("id"));
    oDialog.addCustomData(oField);
    oDialog.open();
}`
```

In the handleConfirm function you can then set value into the field with the id from the custom data:

```
handleConfirm: function(oEvent) {
    var sFieldId = oEvent.getSource().data("field");
    var oField = this.getView().byId(sFieldId);

    var sSelectedValue = oEvent.getParameter("selectedItem");
    oField.setValue(sSelectedValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a datamodel, in which the value is written when selected.
this would need to happen in the controller of the fragment you use to build the searchHelpDialog.
also the model needs to be generated, since the rows of your list probably aren't static.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks friends.
Problem solved.Code;

_handleValueHelp: function(oEvent) {

```
this.selectedValueHelp = oEvent.getSource();
```

}

_handleValueHelpClose: function(oEvent) {

```
        var oSelectedItem = oEvent.getParameter("selectedItem");
        if (oSelectedItem) {
         this.selectedValueHelp.setValue(oSelectedItem.getTitle());
        var productInput = this.getView().byId("helpvalue");
        productInput.setValue(oSelectedItem.getTitle());
        }
    }
```